# python regex can not match if newline exists in string?

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using regex to find time in a string:

```
re.match('.*(\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})', "09-22 13:27")
```

anyway, this is ok, but if `\n` exists, this return `None`:

```
re.match('.*(\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})', "\n09-22 13:27")
```

so why `.*` can not match `\n`? and how to deal with this?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL *"why `.*` can not match `\n`"* - because it's not supposed to.

Comment: Anyway, `.` matches any symbol but a newline. Use `re.S` flag to match a newline with `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude newline by using (?

```
st =  "\n\n09-22 13:27\n"
import re
mo = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d{2}-\d{2}\D+\d{2}:\d{2}(?!\S)',st)
print(mo)
```

Results in:

```
['09-22 13:27']
```

Answer (score 4):

> why `.*` can not match `\n`? and how to deal with this?

[`re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) says:

> `re.DOTALL`
>   Make the `.` special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, `.` will match anything except a newline.

You should note that `.` matches any symbol but a newline. Use `re.S` (`re.DOTALL`) flag to match a newline with `.`:

```
import re
obj = re.match('.*(\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})', "\n09-22 13:27", re.S)
if obj:
    print(obj.group(1))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/D4KbMe)

Comment: in case I'am using re.sub, I tried adding the flag but didn't work. Ended up with a clumsy solution re.finall + replace. Is there a better way?

Comment: @juanIsaza Do you mean you are using something like `re.sub('(.*)\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}', r"\g<1>09-22 13:27", flags=re.S)`?

Comment: sorry, was missing the flags argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
print re.match('.*(\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2})', "\n09-22 13:27".strip())

                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

You can simply `strip` the `newline`.

Comment: What if the string _necessarily_ contains new lines? For example, if it's read from a text file and for some reason you don't want to modify it at all when matching? What if your regex pattern depends on new line characters?

Comment: by default `. matches any character (except for line terminators)`